# How to list a directory in Linux from Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to list all the files and directories under /opt/ in Linux. My code runs in Windows platform. What i have done is reading a config file which consists of all the login credentials of the Linux system but i am not able to list the files or directories even though my Windows machine connects to the Linux server.

```
import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('config.cfg')
USER = config.get('DB_Connector','db.user_name' )
PASSWORD = config.get('DB_Connector','db.password' )
IP = config.get('DB_Connector','db.IP')
```

I wrote a code which will list all the files and directories but that has to be run in Linux only.

```
import os
lst = os.listdir('/opt')
```

But my requirement is to run the code from Windows and get the list. Can someone help me in this?

Comment: Hmm: why is windows all lower case and Linux has a capital?

Comment: Spelling problem was displayed for Linux and didn't show for Windows. Anyhow edited now.

Comment: You forgot to edit the title. The thing is, in a software environment, windows refers to that GUI thing, while Windows refers to the OS. (Yes, it's clear from the context, but it can get confusing: in a virtual machine, you can have windows open in Windows running inside a window.)

Comment: What kind of connection are you establishing with the Linux server? FTP? SSH? SMB? NFS? Something else?

Comment: I am trying for a SSH connection

Comment: I'd look at [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) for the SSH. It is fairly simple to log onto a box, run a command (say `ls /opt`), and get the output back.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to have a look at fabric - a tool to execute commands via ssh. (http://www.fabfile.org/).

To get all files in a directory you can do something like this:

```
from fabric.api import env, run

def set_env():
    env.hosts = ['IP']
    env.user = 'root'
    env.password = 'password'

def list_files():
     files = run('ls /var/www')
     print(files.split("  "))
```

run it with the command "fab set_env list_files"

Comment: I just tested the same code but did not get any output. Don't we require to supply password here?

Comment: You can set a password with env.password = "password". And you can run the script with fab list_files (see http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/tutorial.html).

Comment: I am getting an error
    No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:

Comment: Please post your complete snippet and output…

Comment: **Input**
   `from fabric.api import env, run
    env.hosts = ['IPaddress']
    env.user = 'root' 
    env.password = 'password'

    def list_files():
         files = run('ls /var/www')
         print(files.split("  "))

    list_files()`
**Output**
No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:

I am using pycharm and not command prompt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83212/discussion-between-roshan-r-and-lilith-wittmann).